# how to get international timezone from timezoneoffset method in javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime

I want to get the international timezone (example : +530) from timezoneoffset() method in js (without using any external js libraries) , when i am currently calling timezoneoffset() method on current date it is giving me -330 , i want to know how can i convert it to international timezone , as i know it should be +530 for my current place ,

I need this to come by proper calculation , as i also need to calculate the same from different places.

i want date in this format - "2016-2-6T11:48:0.0Z" , with z being replaced with timezone.

correct date :- "2017-07-06T18:03:39.195+0530"

as you can see in correct date above offset is +0530 , while if i try to get the timezoneoffset on the above date i will get -0330 , how co-relate both timezone and timezoneoffset so i can get timezone from timezoneoffset .

as there is no method to get offset in javascript

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset

Comment: The offset you get i.e. -330 is number of minutes you need to add to current time to get UTC/GMT time so, you need to actually substract 5 hours and 30 minutes as the offset is negative to get UTC time

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
// Get current timezone offset for host device
var x = new Date();
var currentTimeZoneOffsetInHours = x.getTimezoneOffset() / 60;

// Get timezone offset for International Labour Day (1 May) in 2016
var labourDay = new Date(2016,4,1)
var labourDayOffset = labourDay.getTimezoneOffset() / 60;



-------- support desktop browser
Feature         Chrome  Firefox Edge    Internet Explorer   Opera   Safari
Basic Support   (Yes)   (Yes)   (Yes)   5                   (Yes)   (Yes)
```